# Where is the undo button in Linux? If I created an SSH key and copied the public key to a NAS, how would I undo or delete it?

Tags: key-authentication, delete, nas, synology, ssh-keygen

I created an SSH key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

Then I copied the key to the NAS, so I wouldn't have to enter a password using `ssh-copy-id`.

I realized that I did it for the wrong user, so now I need to undo or delete everything.

Also, I changed the permissions:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 711 ~/.ssh
chmod 711 ~
```

Answer (score 2):

An undo button on linux ? There is no such a thing.
Some apps may propose undo features following their own and particular way to rollback.
ssh-copy-id obviously does not.
Worse ? I am not even aware of any automated way to delete an ssh key.

What you can do however is to :

Edit `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in order to remove the line containing your key.

Answer (score 1):

No OS will offer you an undo button for operations other than very simple filesystem manipulations like Move, Copy, Delete and text-editing.
In your case, I believe you'd need a [Versioning file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system) because usually changes to files are written **almost** immediately. In your case, just delete the files manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Roll-back to the previous check-point (you do have one).
- Find and remove the key.

One thing that I do for my public keys, is to have a sub-folder called `public-keys` in `.ssh` to hold by public keys. Then, after updating this folder, I do `( cd ~/.ssh; cat public-keys/* > authorized_keys )`